# String manipulation (replace and reverse) using a function

Tags: python, function, str-replace

all!

Newbie here! I was trying to create a function that would allow me replace four characters (ACTG). To be more concise, I wanted to replace 'A' with 'T' and 'C' with 'G', and vice versa.

The code I have so far is this, but I'm getting an error (translate expected at least 1 arguments, got 0).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

def translate():
    str.replace("A", "T");
    str.replace("C", "G");
    str.replace("G", "C");
    str.replace("T", "A");

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

newdata = indata.translate()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(newdata[::-1])

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

I tried giving translate function an argument (`def translate(str)`) and calling it with str (`newdata = indata.translate(str)`), but those didn't work either.

Would appreciate any help and guidance.

Comment: Your series of `replace` statements is flawed. After you replace every `A` with a `T`, you then replace every `T` with `A` - including all the ones you created with the first `replace`. Your code will end up with nothing but `C` and `A`.

Comment: Hmmm. I didn't realize it would go back and replace them again. I'll look more into it, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a translation table:

```
import string
table = string.maketrans('ACGT', 'TGCA')
```

You can apply the transformation like this:

```
with open(from_file) as f:
    contents = f.read()

contents = contents.translate(table)  # Swap A<->T and C<->G
contents = contents[::-1]  # Reverse the string

with open(to_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(contents)
```

Answer (score 2):

You created a function, not a method.  It does need to take an argument, but you need to pass your string as an argument to the function:

```
def translate(s):
    s = s.replace("A", "T")
    s = s.replace("C", "G")
    s = s.replace("G", "C")
    s = s.replace("T", "A")
    return s
```

You then need to call `translate(indata)`, not `indata.translate()`.

Notice a few other changes I made:

- I named the argument `s` instead of `str`, since `str` is already the name of a builtin type.
- I assigned the result of `replace` back to the variable.  `replace` returns a *new* string with the replacement done.  It doesn't modify the original string.
- I returned the value.  If you don't do this, your function won't accomplish anything.

However, your function still won't work, because the replacements feed into each other.  After you replace A with T, you replace T with A, so As will be changed to Ts and then back into As again.  You should work on your function to try to fix this, but this answer should help you resolve some of the problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time and explaining my mistakes. I really appreciate it. I'll continue to work on this to see if I can find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a `translate()` function built into the `string` module that will basically do what you want.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm

Try something like this:

```
import string

intable = "ACGT"
outtable = "TGCA"
translator = maketrans(intable, outtable)

str = str.translate(translator)
```

That will do the character swap correctly.